# Delete Batch files older than N days on UNC

Tags: batch

I’ve got a macro that pulls data for files in a given path older than N days.

Once identified, I attempted to run a batch file to delete files from the same date specification, but yet a UNC error? Any advice?

Error is UNC File Paths are not supported. I’ve researched it as much as possible, the most consistent advice is to use POPD and PUSHD, however I’m not sure how they would apply for the network drive in the below.

Code:

```
SET log=%temp%\delete.log
SET target.dir= “\\network file path”

ECHO %date%-%time% - Files older than 6 Months that will be deleted>%log%

PAUSE

ECHO %date%-%time% - Deleting Files older than 6 months>>%log%
Forfiles /p %target.dir% /S /D -180 /M *.* /C “cmd /C Del @path”>>%log%
```

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes? You should be using `"`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error is ‘UNC File Paths are not supported’. I’ve edited the post to reflect that error. As opposed to a physical drive, the files are held on a network drive which seems to be the error, but i’ve been unsuccessful in finding a resolve.

Comment: It is trying to set the current directory to the path of the batch file. UNC paths caused a few 30 year old programs to crash (if you closed the command prompt while the program was running) so Windows won't allow it. See Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should do the job:

```
SET "log=%temp%\delete.log"
SET "target.dir=\\network file path"

ECHO %date%-%time% - Files older than 6 Months that will be deleted>>"%log%"

PAUSE
2>>"%log%" pushd "%target.dir%"
>>"%log%" 2>&1 net use %CD:~0,2%
ECHO %date%-%time% - Deleting Files older than 6 months>>"%log%"
Forfiles /S /D -180 /M *.* /C "cmd /C >>""%log%"" 2>&1 Del @path"
popd
```

Explanation:

- Define variables using `SET "variable=string"` syntax pattern and then use them double quoted as `"%variable%"`.
- [PUSHD](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html): When a UNC path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive map and will then use that new drive.
- [`Forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) defaults to current folder if `/p` (the path to search) isn't specified.
- [POPD](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html): `POPD` will also remove any temporary drive maps created by `PUSHD`.
- `>>`, `2>&1`: [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).